# if statement on template literal value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to do the following with no avail: There are a few scenarios where `self.name` has a erroneous '`/`' in the middle of the value; *ie. populating as such* '`WSDH/222-310`' - I am trying to simply catch this and convert it for the value to resolve in my following `.load` call as '`WSDH-222-310`'

```
  if (self.type === "car") {
       var carClean = ${self.name}; // returns syntax error
       var res = str.replace("/", "-");
       console.log(carClean )
       console.log(res)
      //  console.log({self.type});
  }

  self.$container.load(`view/coolObjects/${self.type}/${self.name}`, loadProfile);
```

Comment: You're cleaning the values and storing them in new variables.  What's not working?  I.e., of course your values are not "clean" when you subsequently reference them in the URL as `self.name` (the original value).

Comment: what is `this.${self.name}` supposed to do? It's not in backticks. What is `str`? What is `atmClean`? You are not using the created variables in the last lime at all.

Comment: what is `this` and is it `self`?

Comment: Fix your snippet first please. You're producing a syntax error (which should be obvious) _and_ the `.replace` isn't operating on `carClean` as you probably intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a use case for a tagged template if all embedded variables should be escaped.

> A more advanced form of template literals are tagged templates. Tags allow you to parse template literals with a function. The first argument of a tag function contains an array of string values. The remaining arguments are related to the expressions. In the end, your function can return your manipulated string

Example:

```js
var path = `foo/${x}/${y}/bar`;
```

If both `x` and `y` should be escaped so as to replace `'/'` with `'-'`, then you could do this:

```js
const sanitize_path = (strings, ...parts) =>
  strings
    .flatMap((str, idx) =>
      [ str,
        idx < parts.length
          ? parts[idx].replace(/\//g, '-')
          : '' ])
    .join('');

const x = '1/2/3';
const y = 'y';

console.log(

  sanitize_path`foo/${x}/${y}/bar`
  
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why bother cleaning the strings *before* using them?

I'm not clear on exactly what you're trying to do, but you can "clean" on the fly like this:

```
self.$container.load(`view/coolObjects/${self.type}/${self.name.replace("/","-")}`, loadProfile);
```

Whether or not your surrounding code works, I can't tell.  But here's a working sample of what I'm suggesting:

```js
let self = {"type":"mytype","name":"myname"};
console.log(`view/coolObjects/${self.type}/${self.name.replace("my","your")}`);
```

Comment: That would be because `self.name` is undefined in whatever scenario you're attempting to do a replacement.  You can add checks for that.  Or make sure it's populated.  But if it's undefined, then that points to other problems w/your data that you would have stumbled onto eventually anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then you're on the right track using [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) - should be something simple as this:

```js
var self = {
  name: 'WSDH/222-310'
};

self.name = self.name.replace('/', '-');

console.dir(self);
```